# Query não funcionado, problema para comparar anos

Tags: query, oracle

Olá estou tentando elaborar uma query para realizar um insert, como ela usa apenas dados do banco estou um select para isso.
Meu problema está na cláusula where em que ou fim de operação tem que ser null ou o ano do fim de operação tem que ser menor que periodo, mais precisamente o problema esta na função STRCMP.

```
INSERT INTO EMPRESAS_FILIAL(IDPERIODO, IDEMPRESA, IDFILIAL)
 select ".{IDPERIODO}.", IDEMPRESAS emp, COD_PLANTA fi 
 FROM EMPRESAS emp, FILIAL fi, PERIODO pe 
 WHERE (emp.ASSOCIADO = '1' 
 AND fi.ATUACAORESPONSAVEL = '1' AND fi.ECONOMICO ='1' 
 AND emp.IDEMPRESAS = fi.EMPRESAS_IDEMPRESAS) 
 AND pe.IDPERIODO = ".{IDPERIODO}." 
 AND ( fi.FIMOPERACAO = NULL OR STRCMP(pe.PERIODO, (to_char(fi.FIMOPERACAO, 'YYYY'))) = 1);
```

Ao tentar executar está gerrando este erro: **Erro de SQL: ORA-00904: "STRCMP": identificador inválido
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"**

pe.PERIODO - VARCHAR2
fi.FIMOPERACAO - DATE

Comment: Por que não compara os campos como DATE fazendo a validação necessária? Algo como: `.... AND ( fi.FIMOPERACAO is NULL OR (TO_DATE(to_char(fi.FIMOPERACAO, 'YYYY'), 'YYYY') < TO_DATE(pe.PERIODO, 'YYYY'))`

Comment: Marllon , funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado

Comment: Vou colocar como resposta para ajudar quem tiver a mesma dúvida, ok?

Comment: Valeu mesmo mano :)

Answer (score 2):

Sugiro fazer a comparação por datas.

Algo como:

```
INSERT INTO EMPRESAS_FILIAL(IDPERIODO, IDEMPRESA, IDFILIAL)
 select ".{IDPERIODO}.", IDEMPRESAS emp, COD_PLANTA fi 
 FROM EMPRESAS emp, FILIAL fi, PERIODO pe 
 WHERE (emp.ASSOCIADO = '1' 
 AND fi.ATUACAORESPONSAVEL = '1' AND fi.ECONOMICO ='1' 
 AND emp.IDEMPRESAS = fi.EMPRESAS_IDEMPRESAS) 
 AND pe.IDPERIODO = ".{IDPERIODO}." 
 AND ( fi.FIMOPERACAO is NULL OR (TO_DATE(to_char(fi.FIMOPERACAO, 'YYYY'), 'YYYY') < TO_DATE(pe.PERIODO, 'YYYY'))
```

Repare na extração do ano em ambas as colunas e na conversão para `DATE`